# Search Box Combining two columns (Search Page) ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access, textbox, expression

I having some trouble in my search.aspx page (Search Page)

This is my code:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" ID="AccessDataSource1" DataFile="_private/records.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DriversRecords] WHERE ([LastName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%') OR ([FirstName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%')">
   <SelectParameters>
   <asp:formparameter FormField="LastName1" Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
   <asp:formparameter FormField="LastName1" Name="LastName" Type="String" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

When I type the first name in text box...It's Working the same when i type the last name.

But when i'm trying to **combine** them such us I'm going to type in textbox : "George Santos" the result is "No data found"??

Combing two columns returns to null??
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this SQL instead:

```
SELECT * FROM [DriversRecords] WHERE [FirstName]+' '+[LastName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%'
```

Concatenating the 2 columns (`FirstName` + `LastName` with a single blank space in between `' '`) and then searching for the full name will give you a match provided that `George Santos` is there in the database. :)

If you want to allow multiple ways of searching you can also do this:

```
SELECT * FROM [DriversRecords] WHERE
([LastName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%') OR
([FirstName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%') OR
([FirstName]+' '+[LastName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%')
```

Here's a `SQLFiddle` to test this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae63a/6

Comment: "The server tag is not well formed" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DriversRecords] WHERE ([LastName]+" "+[FirstName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%')" Please help

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM [DriversRecords] WHERE [FirstName]&' '&[LastName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%'`

Comment: STILL ERROR SHOWS "THE SERVER TAG IS NOT WELL FORMED" :(((

Comment: The error is in this tag 
"([FirstName]+" "+[LastName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%')" the same as @Leniel answer.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! Thanks for you answer. I just edit your code a little. i changed the (") into (') single quotation. Thank you again. :)

Comment: +1 However, it is **really unsafe** to use a plus sign as a concatenator in MS Access SQL. If either of the fields are null, null will be returned. The usual concatenator is ampersand ( & ).

Comment: @Remou: see in one of my comments above that I used the ampersand. :) By the way: you're the expert when it comes to MS Access. Congrats for being an active helper at SO. God bless!

Comment: Thank you for the kind comments, it is a pity I am getting so blind :)

Comment: @LenielMacaferi PLEASE CHECK MY NEW PROBLEM. HERE'S THE LINK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262967/data-and-image-are-populated-in-two-rows-i-want-to-bind-them-in-a-single-row