# DATA and IMAGE are populated in two rows. I want to bind them in a single row

Tags: asp.net, database, image, photo, records

I'M GOING TO ASK THIS FOR THE SECOND TIME. I'M GOING TO MAKE IT CLEAR SO YOU CAN HELP ME :) Okay let's start.

I have a Registration Process. I split the process into two page. The first page is for "Personal Information" only. Then when i click the next button the next page will appear (postbackURL) This page is for "Upload Photo" page. They work fine! the data and the image are displayed on my gridview control. But my problem is here: As you can see in the figure below. The data are populated in two rows! I want them to appear in only single row! I think the problem is THE DATABASE FROM PAGE 1 IS NOT CONTINUING. THAT'S WHY WHEN I UPLOAD AN IMAGE IN PAGE 2 THE DATABASE WILL CREATE ANOTHER RECORD. hmmm...what's the problem :) I don't know how to do it. Please help!

THE DATA SHOWN IN THE TABLE BELOW ARE ONLY DUMMY. PLEASE DON'T TAKE IT SERIOUSLY.
[image]

Here's the code for INSERT/UPDATE for PersonalINFO.aspx page:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" ID="AccessDataSource1" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [PendingRecords] WHERE [ID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [PendingRecords] ([Username], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleName], [Address], [Gender], [ContactNumber], [PlateNumber], [Color], [Brand], [LiscensedNumber]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [PendingRecords] SET [Username] = ?, [Password] = ?, [FirstName] = ?, [LastName] = ?, [MiddleName] = ?, [Address] = ?, [Gender] = ?, [ContactNumber] = ?, [PlateNumber] = ?, [Color] = ?, [Brand] = ?, [LiscensedNumber] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?" DataFile="_private/records.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PendingRecords]">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Here's the code for btnUpload_Click in UploadPhoto.aspx page:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/c#">
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


{
    {
   byte[] imageSize = new byte
                 [FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
  HttpPostedFile uploadedImage = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
  uploadedImage.InputStream.Read
     (imageSize, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);
 // Create SQL Connection 
  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
  con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["recordsConnectionString12"].ConnectionString;
 // Create SQL Command 
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PendingRecords([Image])" + " VALUES (@Image)";
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.Connection = con;

 OleDbParameter UploadedImage = new OleDbParameter
              ("@Image", OleDbType.VarBinary, imageSize.Length);

 UploadedImage.Value = imageSize;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(UploadedImage);
 con.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
 GridView1.DataSourceID = "";
 GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
 GridView1.DataBind();
 con.Close();
 }
}
</script>
```

UploadPhoto.aspx page DATASOURCE CODE:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" id="SqlDataSource1" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:recordsConnectionString12.ProviderName %>" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:recordsConnectionString12 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PendingRecords]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [PendingRecords] WHERE [ID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [PendingRecords] ([Username], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleName], [Address], [Gender], [ContactNumber], [PlateNumber], [Color], [Brand], [LiscensedNumber]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [PendingRecords] SET [Username] = ?, [Password] = ?, [FirstName] = ?, [LastName] = ?, [MiddleName] = ?, [Address] = ?, [Gender] = ?, [ContactNumber] = ?, [PlateNumber] = ?, [Color] = ?, [Brand] = ?, [LiscensedNumber] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
        <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass the ID from personal info page to the Upload page (probably via query string).

And then the query for your image update should be and UPDATE query, see below.

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE PendingRecords SET [Image] = @Image WHERE ID = @ID";
```

You'll now pass in the ID parameter as needed.

If the parameter is in the query string ( /UploadPhoto.aspx?id=60 )

```
OleDbParameter UploadedImage = new OleDbParameter
              ("@Image", OleDbType.VarBinary, imageSize.Length);

 UploadedImage.Value = imageSize;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(UploadedImage);

OleDbParameter IdParameter = new OleDbParameter("@ID", Request.QueryString["id"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(IdParameter);
```

Comment: ERROR :)) "Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters." in this line "Line 76:  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  "

Comment: okay i added that code in my quesry string. new error "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Parameter @Image has no default value."

Comment: @PetersonPilares I'm sure you failed to add the image parameter. i've updated my code to show both the image parameter and the id parameter.

Comment: Okay again "Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Parameter @ID has no default value." i copy paste your codes and placed in my query string. Hmmm...my website url is not returning into  /UploadPhoto?id=60 ...in only goes /UploadPhoto

Comment: @PetersonPilares Do u use gmail/yahoo chat .. would be easy to help in that way.